# robot_pose_ekf issue

Tags: imu, navigation, odometry, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have robot that calculates the odometry using the information of the wheels, and what i usually do is publish the odom as a nav_msgs::odometry which has as frame_id "/world" and as child_frame_id "rear_axis"(where all the calculations are made). This setup works with no problem.

Now my problem, I have to combine the information of odometry with the data from an imu(I have an urdf with the right position of the imu->rear_axis), and i was trying to use the robot_pose_ekf to do that.

I made robot_pose_ekf subscribe the information from odometry and from the imu, and I get a tf : /odom->/base_footprint, however i need to connect tf to the previous tf(original).(because I have to acumulate pointcloud while the robot moves)
1.Question: How do I connect these two tf?

2.Question: The frame /base_footprint and /odom(is this like /world frame?) , what does it mean?

3.Question: If the /base_footprint moves with the robot, mabe I can create a static transformation between /base_footprint and my "/rear_axis". (am I completly worng?), to connect the twe tf's tree.

Did I make my self clear?

If anyone could help I'd appreciate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31496/robot_pose_ekf-issue/) by [PedroS.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2042/pedros./) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-04-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-04-09**:
Perhaps you should look at this question that I asked a few months ago http://answers.ros.org/question/11682/robot_pose_ekf-with-an-external-sensor  @Martin_Gunther provided a very clear explanation of all of the frames in robot_pose_ekf

**Comment by [PedroS.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2042/pedros./) on 2012-04-09**:
thanks, it was very useful. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what you state a static transform seems like a reasonable solution.

[REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) covers common coordinate frames used in navigation.  I suggest you follow these naming conventions.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1